# Remove trailing whitespace when a .bat is writing a .txt file

Tags: batch-file, whitespace

The program below reads a .txt file and creates another one. In the process, a string in the input file is replaced for a given value (argument %~1).  Everything is working fine but every line written in the output file is being given a trailing white space.

For example, if the line is "hello" in the input file, it becomes "hello " in the output one. since the output file is actually a program, when I run it I get an undesired result because of those trailing white spaces, I'd like to remove the trailing white space.

```
@echo off > tim-valid-pgm.mac
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
del tim-valid-pgm.mac
set name=%~1
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (model-tim-valid-pgm.txt) do (
set str=%%a
set str=!str:###=%name%!
echo !str! >> tim-valid-pgm.mac
)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is your code, slightly modified:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
set "name=%~1"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (model-tim-valid-pgm.txt) do (
    set "str=%%a"
    set "str=!str:###=%name%!"
    echo !str! >> tim-valid-pgm.mac
)
```

let's see, what happens (`xxd` is to visualize a file in `hex` code):

```
>type model-tim-valid-pgm.txt
###

>xxd -g1 model-tim-valid-pgm.txt
0000000: 23 23 23 0d 0a                                   ###..
```

As you can see, there is no trailing space in `model-tim-valid-pgm.txt`. Now script is running and `tim-valid-pgm.mac` is made:

```
>script.bat ABC123

>type tim-valid-pgm.mac
ABC123

>xxd -g1 tim-valid-pgm.mac
0000000: 41 42 43 31 32 33 20 0d 0a                       ABC123 ..

>for /f "delims=" %a in (tim-valid-pgm.mac) do @echo "%a"
"ABC123 "
```

Now you can see clearly the trailing space (HEX **20**). If you look at your code, the trailing space arises here: `echo !str! >> tim-valid-pgm.mac` in this statement: `!str!`[SPACE]`>>`. To avoid this, use better this code style:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "name=%~1"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (model-tim-valid-pgm.txt) do (
    set "str=%%a"
    set "str=!str:###=%name%!"
    >> tim-valid-pgm.mac echo !str!
)
```

.. output here:

```
>script.bat ABC123

>type tim-valid-pgm.mac
ABC123

>xxd -g1 tim-valid-pgm.mac
0000000: 41 42 43 31 32 33 0d 0a                          ABC123..

>for /f "delims=" %a in (tim-valid-pgm.mac) do @echo "%a"
"ABC123"
```

Now there can't be trailing spaces, even if there are some in the batch script after `!str!`.

Answer (score 0):

if the lines in your list doesnt contain space you can use the variable substition like

```
SET str_with_no_spaces=%str: =%
```

that means replace all space character with nothing in the %str% var

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
echo !str! >> tim-valid-pgm.mac
```

to this and remove the trailing space.

```
>>tim-valid-pgm.mac echo !str!
```

Comment: You mean: to make a long story short :-)

Comment: @Endoro hehe Maybe you should have had the solution, then the explanation.